# How to lookup types of a typedef in JSDoc / use a property of a typedef

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I'm wondering how I can use the property of a typedef:

given:

```
/**
 * The Settings to be passed to the Class
 * @typedef {Object} Settings
 * @property {HTMLElement | SVGElement | Document} [foo=document] foo
 */

/**
 * I want to use the property from a typedef here:
 * @param {Settings.foo} foo
 */
function bar(items) {}
```

This will not work as is. I also tried `Settings['foo']` as [defined in ts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) but that also breaks on "unknown characters".

How to do it in JSDocs without using typescript?
Thank you :)

Comment: [acording to](https://jsdoc.app/tags-typedef.html) seems to [foo=document] foo is a problem. try just use @property {HTMLElement | SVGElement | Document} foo

Comment: It's the same issue. What I am doing for now is adding a single typedef for that object `/** @typedef {HTMLElement | SVGElement | Document} foo */` and then referencing that  one in both, the function `bar` and also the typefed `Object`. It's not ideal but a workaround…